# Remove variable-declaration just for arrow functions?

Tags: typescript, tslint

I prefer to use the form:

```
const myFunc = (): void => {}
```

instead of:

```
function myFunc(): void {}
```

But, with TSLint, it seems to want to see:

```
interface MyFunc { (): void }
const myFunc: MyFunc = (): void => {}
```

Where I find that extra interface for the arrow function super repetitive.  Is it possible to keep all of the type definition requirements in place for the linting profile, but remove this requirement from my arrow functions, without losing the requirements for other variables?

Comment: *with TSLint, it seems to want to see* - it doesn't. If you have TSLint error, please, specify it.

Answer (score 0):

You can either disable the TSLint rule for `variable-declaration` in the `typedef` rule (See https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/typedef/)

Another alternative is to define a generic function definition yourself and use it where you need the type. For example:

```
type Func<A, B> = (a: A) => B;

let myFunc: Func<void, void> = (): void => {};

let myFunc1: Func<number, string> = (i: number) => { return "a"; };
```